# jQuery cookie key value with case statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

Ok, so my code is this so far:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

  // setup the initial display on page load
 var menu_state = $.cookie('atd_gridlist');



  // listen for the clicks
  $('.gridselect').click(function() {
     $.cookie('atd_gridlist', 'grid'); // update (or set) the cookie
     $(".grid").css("display", "block");
     $(".list").css("display", "none");
  });
  $('.listselect').click(function() {
     $.cookie('atd_gridlist', 'list'); // update (or set) the cookie
     $(".grid").css("display", "none");
     $(".list").css("display", "block");
  });

});
```

I need to also check to see if the cookie KEY has already been set, I think a case statement would work but I am not sure how to make the case read just the cookie atd_gridlist key values...

If it is gridselect I need to show the grid div and hide the list div, if it is listselect I need it to show the list div and hide the grid div, if it is not set at all, I want grid div loaded by default and hide the list. I also would like to expire the div every 7 days.

Any help in the right direction is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would something like this do the job?

```
$(function() {    
    var grid = $('.grid');
    var list = $('.list');    
    var stateCookie = 'atd_gridlist';

    var SetStateCookie = function(value) {
        $.cookie(stateCookie, value, { expires: 7, path: '/' });
    }

    var ShowByState = function(state) {
        state = state || 'grid';
        SetStateCookie(state);
        if ('grid' === state) {
            grid.show();
            list.hide();            
        } else if ('list' === state) {
            grid.hide();
            list.show();
        } 
    }

    $('.gridselect').click(function() {
        ShowByState('grid');
    });

    $('.listselect').click(function() {
        ShowByState('list');
    });

    ShowByState($.cookie(stateCookie));
});
```

Comment: Wow, that worked perfect! I wasn't exactly looking for an answer, since I want to learn as I go, but I'm not complaining! Thanks so much!

Comment: Welcome. You can use it as something to lear from still. Just moved your code into a functions, so you do not repeat yourself and added 1 more call with default state 'grid' :D

Comment: Consider approving answer, please :D

Comment: It can be rewritten without jquery, for sure. But this example uses it, and also uses jquery cookie plugin.